# DriverManager vs Tomcat Resource driver selection

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, database-connection

Based only on URL, DriverManager it's selecting the jdbc driver. Why Tomcat Resource tag need driverClassName to select the jdbc driver? It's not enough the URL information?

Comment: If it’s required it will be because of the connection pool mechanics.

Comment: Give me more details. It's not enough the URL information?